# How to retrieve only unique entries from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get some fields from the following database:

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message` text,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `fra` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `til` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

Fra = sender ID; 
til = Receiver ID

That has for example this values:

```
(1, 'This is a message for Obama', '2012-11-14 01:12:06', 1, 3),
(2, 'Hello John! How are you?', '2012-11-14 01:23:43', 3, 1),
(3, 'Hey Jack', '2012-11-14 01:28:11', 1, 2),
(4, 'How are you son?', '2012-11-14 01:28:15', 1, 2),
(5, 'everything allright for you?', '2012-11-14 01:28:23', 1, 2);
```

The way I want to get the fields from the database is at follows: 
I want to get the unique conversations from one user to another. If user 1 has sent a message to user 3, and user 3 replied to user 1, then I would like only to select the last field into the database; Or if user 1 has sent 3 messages to user 2, then I would like to get only the 3rd message to user 2, from user 1. 
So that means I should only get 2 rows as result

I have tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM messages WHERE fra='".$_SESSION['userid']."' OR til='".$_SESSION['userid']."' GROUP BY fra,til"
```

and

```
"SELECT DISTINCT(til) AS til FROM messages WHERE fra='".$_SESSION['userid']."' OR til='".$_SESSION['userid']."'  ORDER BY id DESC"
```

but I can't get the result I want.

Can someone explain me how to do this? 

Edit: I want only to build **threads** of user messages that will show the last message sent between two users (that's the scope of the query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer/example for the sql statement:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae56b/10

```sql
select * 
from messages m1
where m1.date = (select max(m2.date) 
    from messages m2 
    where 
    case when m2.fra < m2.til then m2.fra else m2.til end = 
    case when m1.fra < m1.til then m1.fra else m1.til end
    and 
    case when m2.fra > m2.til then m2.fra else m2.til end = 
    case when m1.fra > m1.til then m1.fra else m1.til end
);
```

Comment: Only gets the latest message between any two parties.

Comment: Yes. This is good. Now I need to get the messages between the current user and another one. The current user is defined by $_SESSION['userid'] variable

Comment: @roshkattu - just remove the last semicolon and add this `and (fra = 3 or til = 3)` if the current user is `3`.

Comment: Let me try please. I have found another workaround after I got the data how you have told me. But I will try directly from the query as you've told me!

Comment: Yeah, just plug that statement into your php and replace the `3`'s with your variable-- though I'd use pdo and placeholders for my variables.  (Nice to have a friend in Romania.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19517/discussion-between-roshkattu-and-marvin)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use group-by also get the values..

select * from messages where ID in (select max(ID)  from messages where fra='".$_SESSION['userid']."' OR til='".$_SESSION['userid']."' GROUP BY fra,til)

Comment: +1, I think this should give you what you want after reading your question again roshkattu.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a case of DISTINCT, it's more a case where you want to limit your result to 1 record. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE fra='".$_SESSION['userid']."' OR til='".$_SESSION['userid']."' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I have tried to do a limit too. But you can't limit the query to 1 row because if I am having for example 5 users that sent over messages to each other, the LIMIT 1 will only show one record, not 5 unique as it should.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry I misunderstood.

Comment: I want only to build **threads** of user messages that will show the last message sent between two users

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use sort of "key=>value" collection to emulate it

your query can be

```
SELECT @discution := (MAX(til,Fra)+","+MIN(til,Fra)) AS key , messages.* FROM messages
 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0 GROUP BY @discution
```